# Delete all records except the 5 most recent ones

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has a PK on id column. I need to clean the table and leave the 5 most recent records (last 5 id's - the most recent ones) in the table.

Except from using `row_number()` is there any other idea how to do it ? 
Thx.

Comment: Are you assuming that the most recent entries will have the highest PK?

Answer (score 4):

First you will want to get the PKs for the five most recent rows:

```
SELECT TOP 5 id FROM [table] ORDER BY id DESC
```

This subquery will return the ids of the 5 most recent rows assuming that the most recent rows will have the highest PKs.

This subquery is then used in the `WHERE` clause of the outer query

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE id NOT IN ([subquery from above])
```

which is equivalent to this

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE id NOT IN (id0, id1, id2, id3, id4)
```

The complete query is then:

```
DELETE FROM [table]
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT TOP 5 id 
                 FROM [table] 
                 ORDER BY id DESC)
```

Comment: Yep , The most recent entries will have the highest PK .

Comment: it's a bit more complicated , The table contains the id column and user code column , the user code column can appear in severl id's . i need to find for each user the top 5 recent records and then delete them in most efficient way .

Comment: Have you ever considered using a `CreatedDate` column? When you `INSERT` the row you simply set this to `getdate()`. Then you can sort your data by the date and time it was inserted. You may also want to use a `ModifiedDate` column which is updated any time you do a row `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thx for the answer but the date is a minor issue , i'm looking for an efficient way to delete rows per user, since for each user i need to get the TOP 5 and then insert to temp table all other records that related to this user and then delete them.

Answer (score 1):

First insert top 5 records in temporary table.
then fire below query..,

Delete from Table_Name

Then insert again (5 records) from temporary table to Main table using below query.,

Insert into Table_Name select * from Temp_Table